# based on id fill up dates for different columns in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2008

Updated question. I have following tables:
project table
projectid, project

stores table
storeid,storename,projectid

projectupdates table
trackerid,projectid, storeid,activityid,date

activity table
activityid, activity

projects may or may not have stores
stores may or may not have activity
for a store an activity can be repeated

With this, I want all the projects, all the
stores and updates for a store.

The activity if present should show only the 
latest date for the activity.

I also want a summary row that counts each 
activity where activity has a date. (if null 
do not count).

I tried with following your code:

```
SELECT     P.ProjectID, S.StoreID, MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Meas Perm Received' THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS MeasPermRcvd, MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Not Visited' THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS NotVisited, MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Not Visited' THEN ReasonID ELSE '' END) AS NotVisitedReason, MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Visited & Measured' THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS Measured
```

FROM dbo.ProjectUpdates AS T INNER JOIN dbo.Project AS P ON T.ProjectID = P.ProjectID INNER JOIN dbo.ProjectStores AS S ON T.StoreID = S.StoreID INNER JOIN dbo.Activity AS A ON T.ActivityID = A.ActivityID
GROUP BY P.ProjectID, S.StoreID

Then I tried with this additional query to get all projects and stores:

```
SELECT dbo.Project.ProjectID, dbo.ProjectStores.StoreID,dbo.StoreTrackerBase.MeasPermRcvd, dbo.StoreTrackerBase.NotVisited, dbo.StoreTrackerBase.NotVisitedReason, dbo.StoreTrackerBase.Measured
```

FROM dbo.Project FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.ProjectStores ON dbo.Project.ProjectID = dbo.ProjectStores.ProjectID FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.StorTrackerBase ON dbo.ProjectStores.StoreID = dbo.StoreTrackerBase.StoreID AND dbo.ProjectStores.ProjectID = dbo.StoreTrackerBase.ProjectID

This is returning all projects and all stores with latest date for activity.
Please advise whether this is good way of coding and whether performance will be good.

Please note I dont have a summary row in this query ( dont know how to do!)
thanks. Krishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'ActivityType' THEN Date END)` with `Group by ProjectName,Store`

```
SELECT
    ProjectName,Store,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Visited' THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS Visited,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'NotVisited' THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS NotVisited,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Finished' THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS Finished
FROM Table1 T
INNER JOIN Project P
ON T.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
INNER JOIN Store S
ON T.StoreID = S.StoreID
INNER JOIN Activity A
ON T.ActivityID = A.ActivityID
GROUP BY ProjectName,Store
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Using MAX will get me either

Comment: I already tried MAX.  MAX will get only one (highest) activity for the store. 
Also it will not get me greatest date for each activity in each store. 


Proejct  Store  Visited             NotVisited  Finished
58 518 2015-04-25 00:00:00 NULL NULL
58 519 2015-04-24 00:00:00 NULL NULL
58 521 2015-04-22 00:00:00 NULL NULL

In my case Store 518, was visited on 25-04 and finished on 28-04.
So it should show both dates under each activity.
The problem is for an activity there could be multiple Visited 
and Finished status. So We want to get the latest date.

Any further help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try my query?

Comment: this is a working example of the query above. the output is exactly same as in your question. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27b39/1). Each `MAX` column get data only for a specific activity using `CASE` and the entire data is then grouped by Project and Store.

Comment: thanks ughai. It works. One clarification - will it show all projects and all stores for the projects?

Comment: dear ughai  how to show all projects and all stores in this query?? thanks.

Comment: Hi I want all the projects and stores to be shown in the report even though there is no activity at all for a store. the above query shows only those stores where there is atleast one activity date. Please help.

Comment: From what you have provided, There is no direct relation between a project and store except your table with columns `ID,ProjectID, StoreID, ActivityID, Date`. provide input data and desired output sample data in the question for your new scenario with table structure